# Bootstrap indicators numbers, change the color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a project for school. I must make a website with Bootstrap 3 exactly like this:[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhMmo.jpg) and [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6EIU.jpg).

I'm almost done with the page, but I am stuck. I want indicator numbers like the picture where I marked in black.

How can I create indicators like that?

After searching on internet I got something like this: https://www.codeseek.co/danbhala/bootstrap-carousel-indicator-with-numbers-gpWvxG. The problem is I can't make the number red after the page has been visited.

Thanks for the help.

Sorry for the bad picture and my English. If something is not clearly stated, ask a question I will answer it.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

#content-container {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel {
 width: 99%;
 margin-left: 0.4%;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#footer {
  min-height: 18%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  background-color: rgba(193, 188, 188, 0.55);
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SelectDate.css">
   <title>Werken met Bootstrap</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <!-- Begin content-container -->
   <div id="content-container">

    <!-- Begin navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="Index.html"><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="font-size:19px; color:red"> </i><b> Hotel</b> Booking</a> 
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="ExploreHotels.html">Explore Hotels</a></li>
       <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End navbar -->

    <!-- Begin Container -->
    <div class="container">
     <h3><b>The Student Hotel The Hague</b></h3>
     <br>  
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">

      <!-- Indicators -->
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
           <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
           <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
           <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
         </ol>

         <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
         <div class="carousel-inner">
           <div class="item active">
              <div class="panel panel-defualt">
               <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Welcome! Let's book a room you'll love.<br>
                 Please provide us with the information started below, we will handle the data with care.
                </p>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top: 3%;">
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Mr</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Mrs</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                  First name:
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                  Last name:
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last name">
                 </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                  Departure Date
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                  Return Date
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                  Rooms
                  <select class="form-control">
             <option>1 Room</option>
             <option>2 Room</option>
             <option>3 Room</option>
             <option>4 Room</option>
               </select>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="pull-right">
                 <a href="#">Cancel &nbsp;&nbsp;</a><a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Pick a room <b>&gt;</b></button>
                 </a>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>

           <div class="item">
             <img src="image/hotel.jpg">
           </div>
         
           <div class="item">
             <img src="image/hotel2.jpg">
           </div>
         </div>

     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Container -->
   </div>
   <!-- End content-contrainer -->

   <!-- Begin Footer -->
   <div id="footer">
    <div class="container text-left">
           <div class="row">

               <!--First column-->
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <h6 class="mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold"><a href="Index.html"><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="font-size:14px;"><b> Hotel</b> Booking</i></a></h6>
                   <ul class="list-unstyled">
                       <li>
                           Niewmansstraat 123
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           1234 AB The Hague
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           The Netherlands
                       </li>
                       <li>
                        <br>
                           &copy; 2018 Hotel Booking
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <!--/.First column-->
     
      <b>
               <!--Second column-->
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <h5 class="mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold"><b>Useful links</b></h5>
                   <ul class="list-unstyled">
                       <li>
                           <a href="ExploreHotels.html">Explore hotels</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">Reviews</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">A link</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">Another link</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">Different link</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <!--/.Second column-->

               <!--Third column-->
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <h5 class="mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold"><b>The Company</b></h5>
                   <ul class="list-unstyled">
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">About</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">Careers</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">Press centre</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#!">Terms & Conditions</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <!--/.Third column-->
            </b>

           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Footer -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please share your code(html + css)

Comment: but you haven't applied any style to the indicators, or if you want to implement from the link you provided then just add `carousel-indicators-numbers li.visited` also in css

Comment: I did and i gave background-color red instead #337ab7. But it doesn't work

Comment: hope you made the necessary changes in 'html' also? i mean adding class to the ol tag

Comment: It doesn't work, that is the hole problem. I tried many ways but still not working. I appreciate if you can show me how it will be red after it's visited and it stays red.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators-numbers li {
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #999;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.carousel-indicators-numbers li.visited, .carousel-indicators-numbers li:hover, .carousel-indicators-numbers li.active {
  margin: 0 2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-numbers">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
</ol>
```